# Appcelerator and Urban Airship. Pushes fires repeatedly

Tags: iphone, appcelerator-mobile

Titanium SDK version: 1.7.0 
iPhone SDK version: 4.2

I am using Urban Airship in my Appcelerator powered iOS app and it works fine. The only problem is that user report getting pushes several times. So if they receive a push and change app and return to my app again. They see the push again. Like it is stuck in memory. How can I show push to users only once.

This is my code that I got in the app.js file. I call the function on app start and on resume.

http://pastie.org/2167458

Thankful for all input!

Answer (score 0):

Line 109:

```
alert(e.data.alert);
```

Would trigger the push alert to be shown in an alert box. Take that out to stop it showing the push again on app launch.